# Texts' size are smaller in Mac OSX than Windows with Qt. I would like to have the same size everywhere

Tags: c++, macos, qt, stylesheet, font-size

I wrote a Qt Application with a GUI customized with Qt Style Sheet. I used the Windows's style for all platforms (Windows, Linux & Mac) but the texts's size is smaller in Mac OSX. I think that the dpi is different but I'm not sure. And I would like to have the same text's size everywhere like in Qt / Windows. Do you know how to do that? in C++ or in Qt Style Sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever working with fonts in the C++ code, this comes to mind:

```
Font font(..., int size, ...) {
    // define font offset based on operating system
#ifdef _WIN32
#define OFFSET 0
#elif __APPLE__
#define OFFSET 2
#endif
    return Font(..., size + OFFSET, ...); 
    // function will return a font that is 2 pts larger on Mac than on Windows
}
```

This is pseudo-code; try this with the Qt font object rather than my hypothetical `Font` class and constructor. Then, instead of calling Qt font constructor, you can use this function to create a Qt font object.

Or perhaps if you're changing the font size of a push button for example:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define OFFSET 0
#elif __APPLE__
#define OFFSET 2
#endif
QFont font = ui->pushButton->font();
font.setPointSize(16 + OFFSET);
ui->pushButton->setFont(font);
```

Comment: Where to put this code ? Everything in my app is in Qt Style Sheet

Comment: I made an addition to my post, showing how you can manually set the font of a push button (as an example).

Comment: I found a solution on stackoverflow. I can change the "font-size" property in the qt style sheet